# How use input.value and get key from object

Tags: javascript, object, key

Hi can someone help me with this?
I want write "company1" in input, take it with input.value and display it in score(paragraph).

Its should look like "write company1 and display in score foil1, foil2 and foil3"

```
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const score = document.querySelector('.score');

const prices = {
    'company1': {
        'foil1': {
            '0-5000m2' : 0.67,
            '5000-10000m2' : 0.65,
            '10000-20000m2' : 0.63
        },
        'foil2': {
            '0-5000m2' : 0.67,
            '5000-10000m2' : 0.65,
            '10000-20000m2' : 0.63
        },
        'foil': {
            '0-5000m2' : 0.67,
            '5000-10000m2' : 0.65,
            '10000-20000m2' : 0.63
        }
    }
}

btnSearch.addEventListener('click',()=>{

const company = input.value;
const foil = Object.keys(company) - I know that here is problem, but dont know how make it correctly
console.log(foil); and here is problem becasue its return numbers = Array(8) [ "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You could like this below. Company name is a key of `prices`. so you should pass the variable as key. And use **[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)** then only you got the object value .That means right side of object

```
Object.values(prices[company])
```

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const btnSearch = document.querySelector('button');


const prices = { 'company1': { 'foil1': { '0-5000m2' : 0.67, '5000-10000m2' : 0.65, '10000-20000m2' : 0.63 }, 'foil2': { '0-5000m2' : 0.67, '5000-10000m2' : 0.65, '10000-20000m2' : 0.63 }, 'foil': { '0-5000m2' : 0.67, '5000-10000m2' : 0.65, '10000-20000m2' : 0.63 } } }

btnSearch.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const company = input.value;
  const foil = Object.values(prices[company])
  console.log(foil)
})
```

```html
<input value="company1"/>
<button type="button">click</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should do `Object.keys(prices)`, right?

Could you please clarify what you actually want to do? Then I can help you better.